# Why is QJsonDocument::fromJson failing to parse a simple value?

Tags: c++, json, qt, qjsondocument

```
QJsonParseError err;
auto doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson ("true", err);
qInfo () << doc.isNull () << err;
```

Output is: `true 5`, which indicates a parsing error, and "5" is `QJsonParseError::IllegalValue`.

The same happens with any simple value tested (`null`, `true`, `false`, numbers and strings).

Why is it an error, although the parsed JSON is valid?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but if you get `true` from `doc.isNull()`, it means that it's not valid. Also, based on my limited knowledge of C++, your `"true"` is a `std::string`, but [`fromJson()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html#fromJson) expects a QByteArray, which is quite different. You should probably do something like `QJsonDocument::fromJson(QByteArray("true"), err);`.

Comment: @musicamante `"test"` is not a `std::string`, it is actually a `const char[5]` array. And yes, `fromJson()` does indeed take a `QByteArray` as input, but `QByteArray` has a constructor which accepts a null-terminated `const char *` pointer, which `"test"` decays into. So `fromJson ("true", ...)` and `fromJson(QByteArray("true"), ...)` are actually functionally identical.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you. I should've thought about that, I suppose that if the conversion weren't possible, it would've raised a quite different error. I initially thought about the single value aspect, but didn't find references in the QJsonDocument docs (at least, not directly, as "an array or an object" misled me), so I assumed that it was considerable accepted. I should've thought more thoroughly... My bad! At least now I've learned something new :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the JSON value you are testing with is *technically* valid, per the JSON standards.  However, Qt's documentation implies that `QJsonDocument` is more limited than the JSON standard allows:

[JSON Support in Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/json.html)

> A valid JSON document is **either an array or an object**, so a document always starts with a square or curly bracket.

Which means `QJsonDocument::fromJson()` simply can't parse simple values, as you are attempting to do.  It can only parse values that are inside of arrays `[...]` or objects `{...}`, eg:

```cpp
auto doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson ("[true]", err);
```

```cpp
auto doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson ("{\"value\":true}", err);
```

Comment: Thanx for explanation. I ended up doing `QJsonDocument::fromJson (("[" + json + "]").toUtf8 ()) [0];` as workaround.

Comment: The string "true" is valid JSON value but isn't valid JSON expression, according to the [standard](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) therefore, the parsing falls fairly.

Comment: @folibis look at the standard again. A JSON expression is a single element, and an element can be a single value of any type. Nothing in the spec says that JSON must begin with only an object or an array

Comment: @RemyLebeau, you're right. I confused the root Element and Object.